# How to display images of products stored on aws s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was practicing on this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZElg91l_ms&t=1234s

It is working absolutely like a charm for me but the thing is I am storing images of products I am storing them in bucket and lets say I upload 4 images they all are uploaded.
but when I am displaying them i got access denied error as I am displaying the list and repeated request are maybe detecting it as a spam

This is how i am trying to fetch them on my react app
//rest of data is from mysql datbase (product name,price)
//100+ products

```
{ products.map((row)=>{

<div className="product-hero"><img src=`http://localhost:3909/images/${row.imgurl}`</div>
<div className="text-center">{row.productName}</div>
})
}
```

as it fetch 100+ products from db and 100 images from aws it fails

Sorry for such detailed question but in short how can i fetch all product images from my bucket

**Note** I am aware that i can get only one image per call so how can I get all images one by one in my scenario

//download code in my app.js

```
const { uploadFile, getFileStream } = require('./s3')

const app = express()

app.get('/images/:key', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params)
  const key = req.params.key
  const readStream = getFileStream(key)

  readStream.pipe(res)
})
```

//s3 file

```
// uploads a file to s3
function uploadFile(file) {
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path)

  const uploadParams = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Body: fileStream,
    Key: file.filename
  }

  return s3.upload(uploadParams).promise()
}
exports.uploadFile = uploadFile


// downloads a file from s3
function getFileStream(fileKey) {
  const downloadParams = {
    Key: fileKey,
    Bucket: bucketName
  }

  return s3.getObject(downloadParams).createReadStream()
}
exports.getFileStream = getFileStream
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your code is sending image requests to your back-end, which retrieves the objects from Amazon S3 and then serves the images in response to the request.

A much better method would be to have the URLs in the HTML page point *directly* to the images stored in Amazon S3. This would be highly scalable and will reduce the load on your web server.

This would require the images to be **public** so that the user's web browser can retrieve the images. The easiest way to do this would be to add a **Bucket Policy** that grants `GetObject` access to all users.

Alternatively, if you do not wish to make the bucket public, you can instead generate [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which are time-limited URLs that provides temporary access to a private object. Your back-end can calculate the pre-signed URL with a couple of lines of code, and the user's web browser will then be able to retrieve private objects from S3 for display on the page.

Comment: I already made my bucket public for all, just to get this working but it will give access denied in heroku console as i am looping and requests are being spammed

Comment: My recommendation is that, instead of serving images from `http://localhost:3909/images/...`, they are served _directly_ from Amazon S3 like `http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/images/...`

Comment: That gives access denied but i have set IAM policies with read and write permission
Screenshot: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZYQIoK026arDhwZv1A7mkBg3himsXqan/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please see my advice above -- you would make the contents of the bucket public by using a **Bucket Policy**, not an IAM policy. This way, anonymous users can access the objects without having to provide any authentication information in the URL. Alternatively, you could use `ACL='public-read'` when creating each object, which will make them public at the object-level. Oh, and also make sure you **deactivate _S3 Block Public Access_** for the Bucket Policy or ACL.

Comment: Sorry for that i mixed it up let me follow the advice as I got this 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-nVij_ESdubvokmZhEzlpd_0oKNm6NlR/view?usp=sharing
If I try accessing it with bucket url

Comment: Hey man really appreciate your attention and advice as it worked, just wanted to know that it is secure right as my bucket is public now?

Comment: If your Bucket Policy is only granting `GetObject` access, then anybody can access an object if they know its key. However, they would not be able to perform other operations such as uploading files or deleting content. So, it depends on what level of "secure" you want. If you want to limit access to only authenticated users, then you can use Pre-signed URLs as referenced above.

Comment: In  my case autheticated user is my node js backend app, so i just want to display images from the bucket to my front end react app 
and i have just selected GetObject

Answer (score 0):

I did sililar S3 image handling while I handle my blog's image upload functionality, but I did not use getFileStream() to upload my image.

Because nothing should be done until the image file is fully processed, I used `fs.readFile(path, callback)` instead to read the data.

My way will generate Buffer Data, but AWS S3 is smart enough to know to intercept this as image. (I have only added suffix in my filename, I don't know how to apply image headers...)

This is my part of code for reference:

```
fs.readFile(imgPath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) { throw err }
        // Once file is read, upload to AWS S3
        const objectParams = {
          Bucket: 'yuyuichiu-personal',
          Key: req.file.filename,
          Body: data
        }
        S3.putObject(objectParams, (err, data) => {
          // store image link and read image with link
        }
}
```

Comment: I am not having any issue when uploading, I just want to display my list of products with their images also i am not using getFileStream() to upload images. I am using it to get images from bucket

Comment: Every uploaded AWS S3 object should have a path that looks like this:

Comment: https://${bucket}.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/${req.file.filename}

Comment: yes, it is like this it works when i want to display a single image without a loop. but as i mentioned in my question that it is working and i want to display list of images then it doesn't works

Comment: That will be your image link, which you can just apply to src attribute in img tag